# HighCharts - Bring gridline to front

Tags: jquery, graph, highcharts

I have a rather simple problem but I can't seem to find anything online to resolve it.

Simply put, I want to have the gridlines on my graph **on top** of the actual graph.  I am currently using the spiderweb graph (    polar: true,
            type: 'area',)

What is not an option:

- I cannot have any transparency on the graph.  The default functionality allows this but it is not an option for me.

Many thanks

Comment: Could you attach any mockup how it should look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the gridZIndex property:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.gridZIndex
- http://jsfiddle.net/yPLVP/39/

  ```
  `gridZIndex: 4`
  ```

The first link is to the Highstock API, but the second link demonstrates that it works for Highcharts too.

Comment: Thank you for the response, you're a life-saver! Sorry I didn't reply sooner, was working all weekend and this got pushed down the priority list! :) thanks!